# Why is std::move undefined although compiler invoked with -std=c++11?

Tags: python, c++, c++11, move

I want to compile kenlm on OSX but I am getting the error:

```
error: no member named 'move' in namespace 'std'
```

Other posts suggest to compile with

> '-std=c++11'

but I am still getting the same error. How can I resolve this?

`g++ --version` outputs:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

---

The build script of kenlm looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import glob
import platform
import os

#Does gcc compile with this header and library?
def compile_test(header, library):
    dummy_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "dummy")
    command = "bash -c \"g++ -include " + header + " -l" + library + " -x c++ - <<<'int main() {}' -o " + dummy_path + " >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && rm " + dummy_path + " 2>/dev/null\""
    return os.system(command) == 0
...

#We don't need -std=c++11 but python seems to be compiled with it now.  https://github.com/kpu/kenlm/issues/86
ARGS = ['-O3', '-DNDEBUG', '-DKENLM_MAX_ORDER=6', '-std=c++11']
ext_modules = [
    Extension(name='kenlm',
        sources=FILES + ['python/kenlm.cpp'],
        language='C++', 
        include_dirs=['.'],
        libraries=LIBS, 
        extra_compile_args=ARGS)
]
...
```

Code using `std::move`:

```
#ifndef UTIL_FILE_STREAM_H
#define UTIL_FILE_STREAM_H
#include <utility>
#include "util/fake_ostream.hh"
#include "util/file.hh"
#include "util/scoped.hh"

#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>

#include <stdint.h>

namespace util {

class FileStream : public FakeOStream<FileStream> {
  public:
    explicit FileStream(int out = -1, std::size_t buffer_size = 8192)
      : buf_(util::MallocOrThrow(std::max<std::size_t>(buffer_size, kToStringMaxBytes))),
        current_(static_cast<char*>(buf_.get())),
        end_(current_ + std::max<std::size_t>(buffer_size, kToStringMaxBytes)),
        fd_(out) {}

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    FileStream(FileStream &&from) noexcept : buf_(std::move(from.buf_)), current_(from.current_), end_(from.end_), fd_(from.fd_) {
      from.end_ = reinterpret_cast<char*>(from.buf_.get());
      from.current_ = from.end_;
    }
#endif
```

Comment: `g++ --version`?

Comment: added to my post

Comment: #include <utility>

Comment: missing include?

Comment: i added the code to my edit that uses std::move. I still get the same error, after adding include <utility> (see code above). Any other ideas why?

Comment: You are building on C++11 or above?

Comment: I am not sure, but g++ version says --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1, see above. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Ceros - `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L` is passed if the code is built as C++11 (at least, assuming an implementation that is correct and compliant with the C++ standard as of March 2011).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [GNU CC Standard Library feature matrix](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), [`std::move` (N2812) §"Impact on the Standard Library"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2812.html#impact-on-the-standard-library) was only added in version 4.5 and revised in version 4.6.

You should update you Standard Library version to version 4.5 (at least). Yours is 4.2.1.